# d3 axis and paths are clipping

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I'm running to a problem where I am trying to create a simple line chart with axes but the line keeps on clipping into the y-axis.

I am using this to setup the axes and the drawing area for the lines.

```
var HEIGHT = 400,
WIDTH = 800,
MARGINS = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
DRAWING_HEIGHT = HEIGHT - MARGINS.top - MARGINS.bottom,
DRAWING_WIDTH = WIDTH - MARGINS.right - MARGINS.left,
xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([0, DRAWING_WIDTH]).domain([1947, 2011]),
yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([DRAWING_HEIGHT, 0]).domain([0, HEIGHT]);

xAxis = d3.svg.axis() 
    .scale(xRange) 
    .tickSize(12) 
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSubdivide(true);

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yRange) 
    .tickSize(10) 
    .orient("left")
    .tickSubdivide(true); 

    visPanel.append("svg:g") 
    .attr("class", "x axis") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + "," + (DRAWING_HEIGHT + MARGINS.top) + ")")
    .call(xAxis); 

visPanel.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ","+ MARGINS.top+ ")")
    .call(yAxis);    

graphableArea = visPanel.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + MARGINS.left + "," + (MARGINS.top) + ")");
```

My line function is then:

```
 var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return xRange(d.year) + MARGINS.right + 0.5; })
    .y(function(d) { return yRange(d.amount) + 0.5; })
    .interpolate("linear");
```

If I remove the MARGINS.right from the ".x(function..." line then the line ends up in the y-axis.

Could some please explain how d3 draws an axis?  that is, after I translate it to a point, does it draw the axis to the right or the left?

Comment: Check out the page on margin conventions - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563. The trick then is to define the width as totalWidth - margin.left - margin.right

Comment: Consider using  "translate(" + MARGINS.left - xAxisOffset, yOffset), xAxisOffset set to 20px instead of xRange(d.year)  + MARGINS.right + 0.5. Best is to not add arbitrary values to your datapoints.

Comment: .orient("left") indicates that ticks and labels should be drawn to the left of the axis line.

Comment: Thanks!  I took a second look at my data and realized that the x axis went from 1946 not 1947, so that year was being given a negative x value...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my dataset was a bit different than I anticipated.  reset the domain of the x scale and it works now.